# Is it possible to create a structure using existing nodes in XSLT 2.0? (so I can then iterate over it)

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to create a structure to iterate over, but its contents should be existing nodes. Like this:

```
<xsl:variable name='my_structure'>
    <rows-to-add>
      <row>existing-node-with-a-specific-path</row>
      <row>existing-node-with-a-specific-path</row>
    </rows-to-add>
    <rows-to-add>
      <row>existing-node-with-a-specific-path</row>
      <row>existing-node-with-a-specific-path</row>
      <row>existing-node-with-a-specific-path</row>
    </rows-to-add>
</xsl:variable>
```

So I can then iterate over $my_structre and apply some logic.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<xsl:copy-of select="existing-node-with-a-specific-path"/>` to copy the nodes into your variable.

One thing that comes to mind is the use of relative URI addresses in your existing data.  When I've done the above, I've added `xml:base-uri="{base-uri(.)}"` into the variable, because without it, then resolving a relative URI would be relative to your stylesheet and not your data.

Comment: is there a way to do it without copying the node (a kind of reference if you will)?

Comment: You cannot have both manifest elements and your concept of a reference.  The memory organization is either a reference:  `<xsl:variable name="x" select="xpath-address"/>` or manifest the content `<xsl:variable name="x"><xsl:copy-of select="xpath-address"/></xsl:variable>`, but not both.

Comment: There is a helpful diagram on page 223 of my XSLT book that is available for free download on a "try and buy" basis at http://www.CraneSoftwrights.com/training/#ptux ... if you decide not to pay for the book, please delete the copy that you download for free.  That diagram distinguishes between the copied nodes and the referencing nodes.